# large MVP application memory leak when opening / closing form

Tags: c#, mvp

I'm working at a project (constructed on the MVP architecture) that has memory leaks. The application is using 1GB of memory with list of records displaying in a Grid.

I profiled it (took the 2 memory snapshots) at these two moments:
1. before opening a page that loads data from a DB (memory usage = 400 MB)
2. when closing the page

When closing the page the memory usage stays the same (around 1 GB), when it should at least drop with something (ideally it should be back at 400 MB but GC can't be always controlled...can it?). I tried to control the process's memory usage like this:

> Process.GetCurrentProcess().MaxWorkingSet = new IntPtr(1000000);

and I intend on using another thing:

`SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr handle, IntPtr min, IntPtr max)`

but I further try to optimize the code and don't know how. I will edit this post with lots of code soon, don't -1...it

Comment: Sorry is this a web application?

Comment: does your program use any native C/C++ components?

Comment: I suggest you leave memory size to the OS and .NET FW. Never had a need to set it manually. Even if you do change it manually you will just cover the problem up. And it will creep again on some other place in your app. Try to find what is using the memory. Maybe use memory profiler from RedGate or JetBrains. They can show what objects are using memory.

Comment: hello, I really can't explicitly find the object to dispose, i profiled the app with ANTS and at the instance Retention Graph it's really all so obfuscated. I'll post the graph and the code associated, maybe you'll be kind enough to point my problem. Thanks

Comment: it does not use native C++ components.. @Siraf

Answer (score 1):

Check if your objects are getting created in Large Objects Heap (LOH). 
Check your event subscriptions too. 
refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx

Comment: it's not a web app @oleksii